# How to prove isomorphism of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ onto $\mathcal{L}(W',V')$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

This question concerns problem 3F 16) in Axler's (2005) "Linear Algebra Done Right".

Assuming that V and W are finite-dimensional vector spaces: how do I prove that a map that takes $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ to $T'\in\mathcal{L}(W',V')$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ onto $\mathcal{L}(W',V')$.

Does it suffice to show that $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\mathcal{L}(W',V')$ have the same dimension (which is fairly easy), or do I need to show that this map is injective as well as surjective? If the latter is the case, why is showing same dimension not enough?

Comment: It's not asking you to show the two $\cal L$s are isomorphic (which you can prove by showing they have the same dimensions), it's asking you to show $T\mapsto T'$ is an isomorphism (which you can't prove just by showing domain and codomain have the same dimension). It suffices to show $T\mapsto T'$ is invertible (or that it's onto and one-to-one).

Comment: Okay, I see this difference. If not a prove for an isomorphism, is the fact that $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\mathcal{L}(W',V')$ have the same dimension enough to say that such map is surjective? Then I only need to prove injectivity (which I managed).

Comment: If you prove injectivity and same dimensions, then surjectivity follows.

Comment: But this would require the isomorphism to be linear, right?

Comment: It wouldn't be a morphism at all if it weren't linear...

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!